# React useEffect not triggering on login redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Description:
I have a website where users can log in and are redirected to the home page upon successful login. On the home page, there's a profile component in the navbar that allows users to view their profile. However, I've noticed that the useEffect hook responsible for loading user data and displaying the profile component is not triggering when the user logs in. As a result, the profile component is not displayed until the page is manually refreshed.

I've ensured that all other code is running correctly, and the issue seems to be isolated to the useEffect hook. It's configured to run on component mount, but it doesn't execute until the page is refreshed.

What could be causing this behavior, and how can I ensure that the useEffect hook runs properly when the user logs in and is redirected to the home page?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```js
const [user, setUser] = useState(true)
const [extUser, setExtUser] = useState()
 const [menu, setMenu] = useState(false)
 
 
 console.log("Component is rendering"); // seeing output on a console



    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("useEffect is getting mounted");
        const getUser = localStorage.getItem("user_token");
        console.log("Token from localStorage:", getUser); // Log retrieved token

        if (getUser) {
            setUser(true);
            let decodedToken = jwtDecode(getUser);
            let somevar = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(decodedToken));
            setExtUser(somevar);
            console.log(somevar);
        }
    }, [user]); // tried removing dependency array but work 

{user ? {display the profile here} : (
                                <button
                                    onClick={() => navigate("/auth")}
                                    className="bg-transparent  hover:bg-gray-500 text-black font-bold  hover:text-white py-2 px-4 border border-slate-500 hover:border-transparent rounded-lg">Login</button>
                            )}
```

Comment: From what I can tell with code you've provided, yes, the `useEffect` hook will run exactly once at the end of the initial render cycle. Are you expecting something to update the `user` state, e.g. call `setUser` and update it to a different value, that is used as a dependency such that the effect will run again?

Comment: Yes, i want to update user state, so that user enable the profile details so that i don't have to manually refresh a page to view changes.

Comment: So, update the `user` state then when a user authenticates in your app? ‍♂️

Comment: @LOKESHR When you go to login page ("/auth"), do you see the log ````console.log("useEffect is getting mounted");```` I think it's already run one time here, then the ````user```` state is not update and it's not running again

Comment: @WestMountain I don't see the console.log("useffect is getting mounted") it's completely ignored.

Comment: Can you make stackblit link

Comment: I never used stackblit, is there any other alternative way?

Comment: Can you [edit] to include a complete [mcve] here in the post? The post should contain all the relevant code and information necessary to understand, and address and answer the question, without and before needing to go off-sight for 3rd-party resources. See also [Help/How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) for additional tips to improve the quality of your post.

Comment: @LOKESHR search "stackblitz react" on google and click the first link

Comment: Just checking on that.

Comment: @WestMountain do you want me to deploy that website?

Comment: @LOKESHR no you put the link to the stackblitz editor, something like this:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-msi7jb?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: press button share at the top

Comment: @WestMountain https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/loki4514/Test

Comment: Error 
User login -> redirect to home page -> home page has navbar -> initially navbar has login button -> after login -> changes to profile button -> to view it i have to refresh it. this is error or a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need both `user` and `extUser` because `user` is more of a derived value of `extUser` unless you want do something else with it but haven't shown in the code.

```js
const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
 
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("useEffect is getting mounted");
        const userToken = localStorage.getItem("user_token");
        console.log("Token from localStorage:", userToken); // Log retrieved token

        if (userToken) {
            const decodedToken = jwtDecode(userToken);
            setUser(JSON.stringify(decodedToken));
        }
    }, []);

{user ? {display the profile here} : (
                                <button
                                    onClick={() => navigate("/auth")}
                                    className="bg-transparent  hover:bg-gray-500 text-black font-bold  hover:text-white py-2 px-4 border border-slate-500 hover:border-transparent rounded-lg">Login</button>
                            )}
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on your description, it seems the useEffect hook might not be triggering as expected due to the dependency on the user state. When the user logs in and you are setting the user state to true, if it’s already true, then React will not recognize it as a change, and consequently, the useEffect will not rerun.

Here’s a suggestion to potentially fix the issue:

Instead of depending on the user state, you could depend on a more specific piece of state that changes when the user logs in, such as the user_token in the local storage.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect is getting mounted");
    const getUserToken = localStorage.getItem("user_token");
    console.log("Token from localStorage:", getUserToken); 

    if (getUserToken) {
        setUser(true);
        let decodedToken = jwtDecode(getUserToken);
        let somevar = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(decodedToken));
        setExtUser(somevar);
    } else {
        setUser(false);
        setExtUser(undefined);
    }
}, []); 

const loginUser = () => {
    localStorage.setItem("user_token", userTokenFromServer);
    setUser((prevUser) => !prevUser); 
};
```